# Conversion of distributive type families of constraints

Tags: haskell, type-families, constraint-kinds

Hypothesis: Type families which result in `Constraint`s are always distributive over their `representational` parameters.

As an example, `` Fam x Eq `And` Fam x Show `` is equivalent to `` Fam x (Eq `And` Show) `` if `Fam`'s second parameter has a representational role.

Questions:

- Is the above hypothesis indeed correct? Are there any references to it?
- Does GHC somehow allow utilising this rule to convert equivalent constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, this breaks down if `Fam x c` uses `c` in a contraviariant way. 
This is now possible using quantified constraints. E.g.

```
Fam x c = (forall a. c a => D a x)
```

for some `D a x :: Constraint`.

(I think this is `representational`, even if I'm not completely positive.)

Hence `` Fam x (Show `And` Eq) `` would mean

```
forall a. (Show a, Eq a) => D a x
```

while `(Fam x Eq, Fam x Show)` would mean

```
( forall a. (Show a) => D a x
, forall a. (Eq a) => D a x )
```

The two constraints are not equivalent. For instance, if `D a x = (Show a, Eq a)` the former is trivially satisfied, while the latter is not.

Comment: Thanks! Now I wonder if a weaker version of my false hypothesis, which can only convert in one direction, i.e `(Fam x Eq, Fam x Show)` to ```Fam x (Show `And` Eq)``` is also invalid.